# Reading a web address in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I can open a web browser using an address saved in a batch file. However, I am looking for a way to save the address when I close the window, without having to manually re-edit the file by hand.

I can read/write to a text file; the only part I am not figuring out is how to access the address of the open web tab. Is this do-able through a batch? Or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: I may re-open a window that is not the last window I had open. If I am shifting between different content, then having it be modular is what I need.

Answer (score -1):

The web browsers save address information either in a file or in Windows registry from where it can be read by a batch script.